# How do I underline the replaced string?

Tags: java, android, replace

For a given string, I want to add underline to a given word/substring.

For example if I have a string `Q1)Sun is a __ .`, I want to make it `Q1)Sun is a _star_ .` (where _ denotes start and end of underline).

I used the below code but it underlines the whole text of the `TextView`.

```
 txtview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

My code:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int er) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        txtview.setText(sen1.replace("__",s.toString());
    }
}
```

So what I will write in edit text,it will get reflect in the text view and replace the "__" with the string in edit text.
The only need is that the changed string should be underline,not the whole text view.

Comment: Your question has two parts, **1.** underline the word "star", **2.** update the string in your `TextWatcher` listener. What have you found out about point 1? And what have you tried so far in step 2?

Comment: Step 2 has no issue,only the problem is with step one.After the update, I want the updated string to be underlined.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
txtview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sen1.replace("__", "<u>" + s.toString() + "</u>")));
```

[image: Demo GIF]

Comment: no, it underlines the whole text view.I want my replaced string only to be underline @DeepakGoyal

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is replacing substring instead of a word. And you may not want that.

For example, if you apply it to a string like `Mr. Wong is a starring character`, it will underline the substring "star".

If you want to do like above, you can use:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(
            yourString.replaceAll("star", "<u>star</u>")));
```

If you want to replace an exact word, you can use:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(
            yourString.replaceAll("\\bstar\\b", "<u>star</u>")));
```

Comment: @G.IJoe if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.